# Field cafe Repository in org.example.CoffeeBewerter.service.TelegramBot required a bean of type 'org.example.CoffeeBewerter.model.CafeRepository' that

Tags: java, spring

I am writing a Spring bot (Telegram) to write information about visited places from the user to the database. Please tell me how to get rid of the error:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
> 2023-12-17T22:17:48.733+05:00 ERROR 5632 --- ${sys:LOGGED_APPLICATION_NAME}[           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field cafeRepository in org.example.CoffeeBewerter.service.TelegramBot required a bean of type 'org.example.CoffeeBewerter.model.CafeRepository' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'org.example.CoffeeBewerter.model.CafeRepository' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 1

My project directory structure is like this:

```
> Blockquote
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOgHD.png)
src/
├── main/
│   └── java/
│       │___ org.example.CoffeeBewerter
│             │
|             │__  model/
|             │      ├── CafeReview.java
|             │      └── CafeRepository.java (Interface)
|             ├── Config/ (Information for DataBase)
|             │── service/
|             │     └── TelegramBot.java
|             └── CoffeeBewerterApplication.java
|
└── resources/
├── application.properties
└── logback.xml

```
> Blockquote
```

CafeReview..java

```
package org.example.CoffeeBewerter.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import java.sql.Timestamp;



@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor@Data
@Entity(name = "review")
public class CafeReview {
    @Id
    private Long idUser;

    private String userName;

    private String nameCafeReview;

    private Integer gradeCafeReview;

    private String commentsCafeReview;

    private Timestamp addReview;

    public Long  geIdtUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void  setIdUser(Integer idReview) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getNameCafeReview() {
        return nameCafeReview;
    }

    public void setNameCafeReview(String nameCafeReview) {
        this.nameCafeReview = nameCafeReview;
    }

    public Integer getGradeCafeReview() {
        return gradeCafeReview;
    }

    public void setGradeCafeReview(Integer gradeCafeReview) {
        this.gradeCafeReview = gradeCafeReview;
    }

    public String getCommentsCafeReview() {
        return commentsCafeReview;
    }

    public void setCommentsCafeReview(String commentsCafeReview) {
        this.commentsCafeReview = commentsCafeReview;
    }

    public Timestamp getAddReview() {
        return addReview;
    }

    public void setAddReview(Timestamp addReview) {
        this.addReview = addReview;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CafeReview{" +
                "idReview=" + idUser +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                ", nameCafeReview='" + nameCafeReview + '\'' +
                ", gradeCafeReview=" + gradeCafeReview +
                ", commentsCafeReview='" + commentsCafeReview + '\'' +
                ", addReview=" + addReview +
                '}';
    }
}
```

CafeRepository.java

```
package org.example.CoffeeBewerter.model;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CafeRepository extends CrudRepository<CafeReview, Long> {

}
```

TelegramBot.java

```
package org.example.CoffeeBewerter.service;

import  org.example.CoffeeBewerter.Config.ConfigBot;


import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.example.CoffeeBewerter.model.CafeRepository;
import org.example.CoffeeBewerter.model.CafeReview;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.commands.SetMyCommands;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.commands.BotCommand;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.commands.scope.BotCommandScopeDefault;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;


import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class TelegramBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    @Autowired
    private CafeRepository cafeRepository;
    final ConfigBot config;

    static final String HELP_TEXT = "///";

    public TelegramBot(ConfigBot config){
        this.config = config;
        List <BotCommand> listOfCommands = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfCommands.add(new BotCommand("/start", "Start to bot"));
        listOfCommands.add(new BotCommand("/grade", "Add a cafe review"));
        listOfCommands.add(new BotCommand("/review", "View the cafe's review"));
        listOfCommands.add(new BotCommand("/deletereview", "Delete a cafe's review"));
        listOfCommands.add(new BotCommand("/help", "Information on how to use the bot"));
        try {
            this.execute(new SetMyCommands(listOfCommands, new BotCommandScopeDefault(), null));
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            log.error("Error setting bot's command list: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return config.getBotName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return config.getToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()){
            String TextMessage = update.getMessage().getText();
            long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();

            switch (TextMessage){
                case "/start":
                    startBot(chatId, update.getMessage().getChat().getFirstName());
                    break;
                case "/grade":
                    SendMessage mesCafe = new SendMessage();
                    mesCafe.setText("Write the name of the coffee shop, a rating from 1 to 5 and a comment (separated by a space)");
                    registerReview(update.getMessage(), String.valueOf(mesCafe));
                case "/help":
                    sendMessage(chatId, HELP_TEXT);
                    break;
                default: sendMessage(chatId, "Unfortunately, this is not supported right now.");

            }
        }
    }

    private void registerReview(Message message, String msg){
        var charId= message.getChatId();
        var chat = message.getChat();

        CafeReview cafeReview = new CafeReview();

        cafeReview.setIdUser(Math.toIntExact(charId));
        cafeReview.setUserName(chat.getUserName());

        String[] strings = msg.split(" ");
        cafeReview.setNameCafeReview(strings[0]);
        cafeReview.setGradeCafeReview(Integer.valueOf(strings[1]));
        cafeReview.setCommentsCafeReview(strings[2]);

        cafeReview.setAddReview(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        cafeRepository.save(cafeReview);
        log.info("Review saved");
    }

    private void startBot(long chatId, String nameUser){
        String answer = "Hi, " + nameUser + ". Choose a command";
        log.info("Replied to user" + nameUser);
        sendMessage(chatId, answer);
    }

    private void sendMessage(long chatId, String textToSend){
        SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
        message.setChatId(String.valueOf(chatId));
        message.setText(textToSend);

        try {
            execute(message);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e){
            log.error("Error occured" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

I tried adding it to service/TelegramBot.java @Service, it didn't help. I tried adding @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={
"org.example.something", "org.example.application"}). The bot stopped responding